# Galaxy S21: How do I leave my mobile hotspot turned on 24/7?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I'd like to have my mobile hotspot turned on 24/7. Currently, it gets turned off it's not being used for a while. How do I disable this behavior make it permanently turned on?

Comment: I guess you can't. Mobile Hotspot consumes battery, a lot, and is disabled after a while when not used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this forever but one way to keep it on longer is to make sure you, Auto connect to wifi' option is off.  Otherwise, when you go to a spot where you previously saved a known wifi connection, it will auto connect an hotspot can not stay on if wifi is on.